# How to bind jbossws properties files to soap request and response message in soapui?

Tags: soap, soapui, ws-security

As  you know, in wildfly ws-security configuration, 2 properties files are binded to web service. In server side server.properties is binded like below,

== server.properties

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=password123
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=servicekey
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=META-INF/serviceKeystore.jks
```

== jaxws-endpoint-config.xml

```
<endpoint-config>     
   <config-name>Custom WS-Security Endpoint</config-name>     
   <property>       
      <property-name>ws-security.signature.properties</property-name>       
      <property-value>META-INF/server.properties</property-value>     
   </property>     
   <property>       
      <property-name>ws-security.callback-handler</property-name>       
      <property-value>
      com.aaa.soap.KeystorePasswordCallback
      </property-value>        
   </property>   
   </endpoint-config>
```

== HelloWorld.java

```
@WebService
@EndpointConfig(configFile = "WEB-INF/jaxws-endpoint-config.xml", configName = "Custom WS-Security Endpoint")
public class HelloWorld implements IHelloWorld {
    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

In client side, JSP files are binding client.properties to soap request.

== client.properties

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=password123
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=servicekey
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=META-INF/serviceKeystore.jks
```

== index.jsp

```
<body>
<% 
String SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/SOAPEncryptWeb/HelloWorld";

try {
    QName serviceName = new QName("http://soap.aaa.com/", "HelloWorldService");

    URL wsdlURL;
    wsdlURL = new URL(SERVICE_URL + "?wsdl");
    Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);

    IHelloWorld port = (IHelloWorld) service.getPort(IHelloWorld.class); 

    ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER, new KeystorePasswordCallback());
    ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_PROPERTIES, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/client.properties"));
    ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_USERNAME, "servicekey");
    out.println(port.sayHello("jina"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
```

So in soapui application I remake these client/server properties like below,

[image][image]

But I am stuck on this part. These server and client properties are binded successfully on Eclipse IDE. However in SoapUI application I have no idea how to bind these properties with soap request and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use *WS Security* on *SOAPUI* you've to use its specific *WS-Security configuration* as follows. First double click in your project name on *Navigator* window:

[image]

Here as you can see in the image above, there is a *WS-Security Configurations* tab.

First of all add your keystore which contains the key to perform the operations. To do so, click on the *Keystores* tab and add your keystore information, in your case based on your `clients.properties`:

[image]

Second, based on your code seems that you want to encrypt the outgoing message to the web service , so select the *Outgoing WS-Security Configuration* tab and add a new configuration. Your outgoing/incoming properties are in `WEB-INF/jaxws-endpoint-config.xml` config file which you're not showing in your question, so configure this tabs based on the content of this file. Once configured it could looks like:

[image]

Finally to check your configuration, go to your *SOAP Request*, right click on the request panel and select *Outgoing wss > Apply [your ws cfg name]*:

[image]

For more detailed info, check the [*SOAPUI documentation*](https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/ws-security.html)

I hope this points your on the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With your advice, I set wss configuration in soapui. But in the last step which applies [my ws cfg name] on SOAP request, I face the exception. This is my soap message format, <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.aaa.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:sayHello>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>Jina</arg0>
      </soap:sayHello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>  And the fault is "Missing message part with name [{http://soap.aaa.com}sayHello]. Any advice?

Comment: @JosephHwang sorry for my delayed reply but I'm out for a days... finally Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am afraid I am still stuck with this issue. Pls, check this thread. **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938239/validation-of-encrypted-soap-request-throws-the-error-fault**