# How to configure Manifest.mf in soapui?

Tags: soapui, ws-security, manifest.mf

As you know, I have to add the following jars in **META-INF\MANIFEST.MF** file for wildfly ws-security configuration,

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.apache.cxf.impl, org.apache.ws.security, org.jboss.ws.api services
Class-Path:
```

What is the soapui function to add necessary jars in soapui ws-security configuration like **META-INF\MANIFEST.MF** file in wildfly if there is the similar menu.

**UPDATE**

When I accomplished to deploy ws-security service in wildfly, my last step was to add wildfly web service jars dependencies in **META-INF\MANIFEST.MF** file like above. But in soapui ws-security project I have no knowledge what web service tool is default and how to change the soapui default ws tools to jbossws. This link is my clue:

[Validation of encrypted SOAP request throws the error fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938239/validation-of-encrypted-soap-request-throws-the-error-fault)

The encrypted soap message with soapui default ws tools can't be allowed in wildfly web service.

```
line 6:Element not allowed: EncryptedData@http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc# in element arg0
```

So I think I have to configure soapui ws-security with jbossws tools to interact client soap message with wildfly web service. I copied every jbossws related jars into /bin/ext folders but nothing changes. If this is right, I do want to know how to configure the default ws-tools.

Comment: The question does not have the context and unclear. Would you mind adding details such as what ate you trying to achieve and the problem being faced or how some one can replicate the same.

Comment: According to your advice, I add more comments from **UPDATE**. I hope these comments will be helpful.